# Add custom button into jqGrid ColumnChooser dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jqgrid, column-chooser

i want to add custom button into ColumnChooser dialog box and make it to behave like others. I try to get something like [this(Default button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wxhw.png)

```
  _this.table.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", _this.pid, {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "icon",
    title: "Title",
    onClickButton: function() {
      return self.table.jqGrid("columnChooser", {
        done: function(perm) {
          if (perm) {   
            self.table.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
            return $(window).triggerHandler("resize.jqGrid");
          }
        },
        dialog_opts: {
          modal: true,
          resizable: false
        },
        msel_opts: {
          dividerLocation: 0.5
        },
        width: 460
      });

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
onClickButton: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser", {
        dialog_opts: {
            buttons: {
                Default: function () {
                    alert("Default button is clicked!");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/columnChooserCustumButton.htm) displays the following results:

[image]