# Make JqGrid Column Chooser Pop-Up Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am trying to make jqgrid column chooser pop-up draggable anywhere in the screen.

Hence I tried to change the `jquery.jqgrid.js` as:

```
columnChooser: function (opts) {
    var self = this;
    if ($("#colchooser_" + $.jgrid.jqID(self[0].p.id)).length) { return; }
    var selector = $('<div id="colchooser_' + self[0].p.id + '" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden"><div><select multiple="multiple"></select></div></div>');
    var select = $('select', selector);

    function insert(perm, i, v) {
        if (i >= 0) {
            var a = perm.slice();
            var b = a.splice(i, Math.max(perm.length - i, i));
            if (i > perm.length) { i = perm.length; }
            a[i] = v;
            return a.concat(b);
        }
    }
    opts = $.extend({
        "width": 'auto',
        "height": 260,
        "classname": null,
        "done": function (perm) { if (perm) { self.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true); } },
        /* msel is either the name of a ui widget class that
        extends a multiselect, or a function that supports
        creating a multiselect object (with no argument,
        or when passed an object), and destroying it (when
        passed the string "destroy"). */
        "msel": "multiselect",
        /* "msel_opts" : {}, */

        /* dlog is either the name of a ui widget class that 
        behaves in a dialog-like way, or a function, that
        supports creating a dialog (when passed dlog_opts)
        or destroying a dialog (when passed the string
        "destroy")
        */
        "dlog": "dialog",
        "dialog_opts": {
            "minWidth": 550
        },
        "draggable": function (IsDraggable) {
            if (IsDraggable) {
                this.draggable();
            }

        },

       ....
       ....
       ....
       ....
       ....
}
```

My code is at the last property `draggable` of the above function. 
i.e. I created a draggable property which is like the below:

```
"draggable": function (IsDraggable) {
    if (IsDraggable) {
        this.draggable();
}
```

But my pop-up of my column chooser doesnot becomes draggable.

I am struck here.
I want to move my column chooser in `jqgrid` anywhere in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should never ever to modify the code of `jquery.jqgrid.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`. Instead of that you can always use `$.jgrid.extend(...);` to *replace* jqGrid method `columnChooser`, for example, to new implementation. See [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688942/315935) as an example.

I suppose that the origin of your problem is missing JavaScript or CSS file which you have to include. It's important to understand that `columnChooser` uses Multiselect plugin `ui.multiselect.js` and `ui.multiselect.css`, which is implemented as jQuery UI widget. Thus one have to include `jquery-ui.min.js` too and not just `jquery-ui.min.css`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_singleSelect.htm) as an example of CSS and JS files which you should included or [more simple demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/columnChooserCustumButton.htm), created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34352530/315935).

Comment: Yes. I accept that. I am in a project, where I am trying to implement that feature in the jqgrid. After this try succeeds, I will extend the jqgrid column chooser. And of course I have included all the files which you have mentioned.

Comment: @Vikash: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/columnChooserCustumButton.htm) for example. The dialog can be moved by drag&drop, the visible column can be reorderd inside of the left pane or can be make hidden by drag&drom from the left pane to the right one. What other drag&drop functionality are still missing in the demo? You can open the code and see all files included in the demo.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the solution.

Comment: I answered the question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. What the problem is, I have fixed the `top` and `left` property in CSS and marked it as `!important`. So, when I drag the pop-up, the top and left position changes the value(which we can see through the browser's console window), but it never moves due to the `!important` I have set.

Now I resolved the problem by not setting the `top` and `left` property as !important.

**Wrong one:**

```
.ui-dialog{
    top: 10px !important;
    left 10px !important;
 }
```

The above is wrong. We should not the set the `top` and `left`.

**Corrected as:**

```
 .ui-dialog{
    top: 10px;
    left 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Which exact CSS rules you added? `top: 10px !important left 10px !important` is not CSS rule you should add the class names. Moreover you should add the information about the version of jqGrid and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) which you use. Could you reproduce the problem in my demos? If not then the problem exists because of **some other CSS**. I suppose the origin of the problem you should mention *which CSS** set `top` which you need to overwrite with `!important`.

Comment: Please, write short comment if you changes the text of your answer. You wrote now that one should remove `!important;` from `.ui-dialog{ top: 10px !important; left 10px !important; }`, but I don't know the setting in no jqGrid CSS, neither from free jqGrid nor in Guriddo jqGrud JS CSS. Even old jqGrid version don't have the setting. Could your inform other readers **which CSS had the wrong settings which was the origin of your problem**? Is it a bug of some jqGrid version/fork or it was the bug of your custom CSS settings?